# Get attributes of child product magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I need to generate a custom XML schema in magento 1.8.0 with some info of my configurable products. In these info, I need to fetch some attributes (size, color) from the simple products for each configurable. This is a relevant piece of my code so far, which generates my XML fine, except the fact I can't find a way to fetch the attributes 'color' and 'shirt_size' from the simple products.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
foreach ($products as $product_all) {
    $sku = $product_all->getSku(); 
    $price = $product_all->getPrice();

    $prod = $xml->addChild('product');
    $prod->addChild('product_id', "$sku");
    $prod->addChild('price', "$price");
    $prod->addChild('color', "");
    $prod->addChild('shirt_size', "");
}
print($xml->asXML());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, which loads the child products then gets the attribute values of their configured options:

```
foreach ($products as $product_all) {
    ...
    $prod = $xml->addChild('product');
    ...

    /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product_all */
    if ($product_all->isConfigurable()) {
        $options = $product_all->getOptionList();
        /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable $type */
        $type = $product_all->getTypeInstance();
        $children = $type->getUsedProducts(null, $product_all);
        /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $prod->addChild($option->code, $child->getAttributeText($option->code));
            }
        }
    }
}
```